# Get Dropdown value in Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

I have 4 dropdowns - From and To for month selection; from and to for Year selection. In my javascript function, I need to display an alert in case I select From month greater than To month of the same year in both the dropdowns. (Ex. July 2013 - April 2013, which is logically incorrect).

Following is my code.

```
var pStartMonth = $('#<%= cboMonth1.ClientID %>').val();
var pStartYear = $('#<%= cboYear1.ClientID%>').val();
var pEndMonth = $('#<%= cboMonth2.ClientID%>').val();
var pEndYear = $('#<%= cboYear2.ClientID%>').val();

if ((pStartMonth > pEndMonth) && (pStartYear == pEndYear)) {
   arguments.IsValid = true;
   alert("Preferred Start Month should be lesser than Preferred End Month");
}
```

My issue is,(say I select **July 2013 - April 2013**) till the execution comes to the IF loop, the value of **pStartMonth** is 7 and **pEndMonth** is 4. The moment it crosses this line, both From and To Momths have the value 7. Where is the issue?

**EDIT**

My HTML codes.

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="cboMonth1" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true" onclick="javascript:shouldsubmit=false;" ValidationGroup="vTimeSlot">
                                <asp:ListItem Value="0">-Select-</asp:ListItem>
                                <asp:ListItem Value="1">January</asp:ListItem>
                                <asp:ListItem Value="2">February</asp:ListItem>
                                <asp:ListItem Value="3">March</asp:ListItem>
                                <asp:ListItem Value="4">April</asp:ListItem>
                                <asp:ListItem Value="5">May</asp:ListItem>
                                <asp:ListItem Value="6">June</asp:ListItem>
                                <asp:ListItem Value="7">July</asp:ListItem>
                                <asp:ListItem Value="8">August</asp:ListItem>
                                <asp:ListItem Value="9">September</asp:ListItem>
                                <asp:ListItem Value="10">October</asp:ListItem>
                                <asp:ListItem Value="11">November</asp:ListItem>
                                <asp:ListItem Value="12">December</asp:ListItem>
                            </asp:DropDownList>
                            <font color="red">*</font>
                            <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="cboMonth1_RequiredFieldValidator" runat="server"
                                ErrorMessage="Start Month Required" ForeColor="Red" Font-Size="0.9em" ControlToValidate="cboMonth1" ValidationGroup="vTimeSlot" Display="None"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>

                            <asp:DropDownList ID="cboYear1" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true" onclick="javascript:shouldsubmit=false;">
                                <asp:ListItem Value="0">-Select-</asp:ListItem>
                                <asp:ListItem Value="2013">2013</asp:ListItem>
                                <asp:ListItem Value="2014">2014</asp:ListItem>
                                <asp:ListItem Value="2015">2015</asp:ListItem>
                                <asp:ListItem Value="2016">2016</asp:ListItem>
                                <asp:ListItem Value="2017">2017</asp:ListItem>
                                <asp:ListItem Value="2018">2018</asp:ListItem>
                                <asp:ListItem Value="2019">2019</asp:ListItem>
                                <asp:ListItem Value="2020">2020</asp:ListItem>
                                <asp:ListItem Value="2021">2021</asp:ListItem>
                                <asp:ListItem Value="2022">2022</asp:ListItem>
                                <asp:ListItem Value="2023">2023</asp:ListItem>
                                <asp:ListItem Value="2024">2024</asp:ListItem>
                            </asp:DropDownList>
                            <font color="red">*</font>
                            <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="cboYear1_RequiredFieldValidator" runat="server"
                                ErrorMessage="Start Year Required" ForeColor="Red" Font-Size="0.9em" ControlToValidate="cboYear1" ValidationGroup="vTimeSlot" Display="None"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>

<asp:DropDownList ID="cboMonth2" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true"     onclick="javascript:shouldsubmit=false;">
                                <asp:ListItem Value="0">-Select-</asp:ListItem>
                                <asp:ListItem Value="1">January</asp:ListItem>
                                <asp:ListItem Value="2">February</asp:ListItem>
                                <asp:ListItem Value="3">March</asp:ListItem>
                                <asp:ListItem Value="4">April</asp:ListItem>
                                <asp:ListItem Value="5">May</asp:ListItem>
                                <asp:ListItem Value="6">June</asp:ListItem>
                                <asp:ListItem Value="7">July</asp:ListItem>
                                <asp:ListItem Value="8">August</asp:ListItem>
                                <asp:ListItem Value="9">September</asp:ListItem>
                                <asp:ListItem Value="10">October</asp:ListItem>
                                <asp:ListItem Value="11">November</asp:ListItem>
                                <asp:ListItem Value="12">December</asp:ListItem>
                            </asp:DropDownList>
                            <font color="red">*</font>
                            <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="cboMonth2_RequiredFieldValidator" runat="server"
                                ErrorMessage="End Month Required" ForeColor="Red" Font-Size="0.9em" ControlToValidate="cboMonth2" ValidationGroup="vTimeSlot" Display="None"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>

                            <asp:DropDownList ID="cboYear2" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true" ValidationGroup="vTimeSlot" >
                                <asp:ListItem Value="0">-Select-</asp:ListItem>
                                <asp:ListItem Value="2013">2013</asp:ListItem>
                                <asp:ListItem Value="2014">2014</asp:ListItem>
                                <asp:ListItem Value="2015">2015</asp:ListItem>
                                <asp:ListItem Value="2016">2016</asp:ListItem>
                                <asp:ListItem Value="2017">2017</asp:ListItem>
                                <asp:ListItem Value="2018">2018</asp:ListItem>
                                <asp:ListItem Value="2019">2019</asp:ListItem>
                                <asp:ListItem Value="2020">2020</asp:ListItem>
                                <asp:ListItem Value="2021">2021</asp:ListItem>
                                <asp:ListItem Value="2022">2022</asp:ListItem>
                                <asp:ListItem Value="2023">2023</asp:ListItem>
                                <asp:ListItem Value="2024">2024</asp:ListItem>
                            </asp:DropDownList>
```

Comment: Can you provide your HTML markup and/or a demo on jsfiddle?

Comment: @IrvinDomininakaEdward, pl check my edited question.

Comment: @Aishvarya, Actually Irvin is asking for the sample html code!!! please provide the html code or jsfiddle.

Comment: @AyyappanSekar, I have included that in my post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how I would approach this problem:

```
// Your variable assignments
var pStartMonth = $('#<%= cboMonth1.ClientID %>').val(),
    pStartYear = $('#<%= cboYear1.ClientID%>').val(),
    pEndMonth = $('#<%= cboMonth2.ClientID%>').val(),
    pEndYear = $('#<%= cboYear2.ClientID%>').val();

// Strongly typed date objects initialised to epoch
var startDate = new Date(0),
    endDate = new Date(0);

// Set the individual components that we have to play with
startDate.setFullYear(pStartYear);
startDate.setMonth(pStartMonth);
endDate.setFullYear(pEndYear);
endDate.setMonth(pEndMonth);

// Do the comparison using the date objects
if (startDate > endDate) {
    // Handle invalid case
}
```

Hope this helps!